# How can ı sort dataframe without specific columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table like below

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 5 | 32 |
| b | 5 | 3 | 10 |
| c | 8 | 22 | 9 |
| d | 12 | 2 | 1 |
| e | 1 | 10 | 13 |

I want to sort from highest to lowest by looking at each column and row as follows

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 5 | **32** |
| c | 8 | **22** | 9 |
| e | 1 | 10 | **13** |
| d | **12** | 2 | 1 |
| b | 5 | 3 | **10** |

Comment: `df[order(do.call(pmax, df[-1]), decreasing = TRUE), ]`

Comment: `df %>%
  arrange(desc(pmax(x2, x3, x4))) ` using `dplyr`